# bash if statement expected unary operator

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement

I'm trying to do something along lines of

```
if (!regular file || symbolic link)
    continue
```

What I have so far is

```
st1=$( -f "${ARRAY[$i]}" )                                                 
 if [ "$st1" -eq 0 ]
```

but I'm getting "expected unary operator error"

Comment: What is wrong with `if [[ -f $file ]] || [[ -L $file ]]`?

Comment: `st1=$( -f "${ARRAY[$i]}" )` doesn't make sense. The `$( ... )` construct requires a *command* between the parentheses. `-f` is not a command; it's an argument to the `test`, `[`, or `[[` command. You should have gotten an error like `bash: -f: command not found`, not `expected unary operator`; did you copy-and-paste your *exact* code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create intermediate `st1` variable. Just use:

```
if [[ ! -f "${ARRAY[$i]}" || -h "${ARRAY[$i]}" ]]; then
    echo "${ARRAY[$i]} link exists"
fi
```

Your use of `st1=$( -f "${ARRAY[$i]}" )` is incorrect and will cause syntax error:

```
-f: command not found
```

since shell will consider `f` as a command name.

Comment: Okay but what was the problem?

Comment: I think I mentioned about *intermediate variable* creation. Let me add more explanation.

Comment: Please, don't wrap non-code in code formatting. :P (Answer is better now, assuming it's correct (I don't know))

Comment: It should be an OR operator instead of AND, but the rest of it helped, thank you

Comment: Oh right, it is updated now. Glad it all worked out.